# How can i have greaterThan and equalTo in validation for the same string?

Tags: jquery, validate.js

I am using validate.js to check the dates. I want end date to be equal to or greater than start date. how do I check this using jquery? Can I have two rules to the above jquery?

```
$("#edate").rules("add", {
    greaterThan: "#sdate",
    messages: {
        greaterThan: "end date must be greater than start date"
    }
});
```

Comment: That is neither [tag:php] nor [tag:mysql]. How to do a greater-or-equal depends on what library that is.

Comment: I am using validate.js to check the dates. I want end date to be equal to or grater than start date. how do i check this using jquery? Can i have to rules to the above jquery?